# `method_missing': undefined method `mail' for Emailer:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am studying Peter Cooper's book Beginning Ruby. 
There is a simple example in it using ActionMailer to send an an email.
The example code is below:

```
require 'action_mailer'

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.mail.yahoo.com",
    :port => 465,
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => "username@yahoo.com",
    :password => "password",
    :openssl_verify_mode => :ssl
}

class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def self.test_email(email_address, email_body)
    mail(to: email_address, from: 'username@yahoo.com', subject: 'action mailer test', body: email_body)
  end
end

Emailer.test_email('username@gmail.com', 'This is a test e-mail!').deliver_now
```

As you can see, I want to use yahoo's smtp server to send an email to my gmail account. I provide to ActionMailer::Base the required [smtp setting](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) and created the class method `test_email` to send an email with the `main` method and the `deliver_now` method. However I receive the following error message:

```
/home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@beginning_ruby/gems/actionmailer-5.2.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:582:in `method_missing': undefined method `mail' for Emailer:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I also tried to change the `test_email` method into an instance method and use `Emailer.new.test_email`...In this case the error message I receive is:

```
/home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@beginning_ruby/gems/mail-2.7.0/lib/mail/message.rb:1396:in `method_missing': undefined method `deliver_now' for #<Mail::Message:0x0000000002e0eac8> (NoMethodError)
```

I have no idea why method `mail` first and then method `deliver_now` are not recognized, being instead both methods belonging to [ActionMailer::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail) in Ruby 5.2.0.

--- edited --
If I remove `self` from the `test_email` method, as it originally was in the book (I thought it was a mistake), when I run the rb file containing the above code I receive a long traceback (21 lines) with the following error message:

```
/home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:189:in `rbuf_fill': end of file reached (EOFError)
```

According to the author ActionMailer can be used independently of Rails.
So I installed the ActionMailer gem in a dedicated rvm gemset and wrote the code above in a `rb` file, code extracted from the book. Running this script I receive the EOFError error. All my attempts of making it work, such as adding `self` to the `test_email` method or calling method `test_email` on an instance of class Emailer failed.

Comment: I guess you should make `test_email` method an instance method of `Emailer` class, not its singleton method.

Comment: As I wrote I also tried to make `test_email` an instance method removing `self` and calling `test_mail` on an instance of the class `Emailer` but I receive a different error

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: It is up there: undefined method `deliver_now'

Comment: Try `deliver`, as far as I remember, this has changed in Rails 5.

Comment: With `deliver` I receive another different error: `end of file reached (EOFError)`

Comment: @Asarluhi: make it an instance method, but __call__ it as a class method. Action mailer classes are weird like that.

Comment: Using `test_email` as an instance method and calling 'Emailer.test_email' (which is the correct form) I receive a `end of file reached (EOFError)` error message

Comment: @Asarluhi: you messed up your ends while you were editing the file. Check that there's an `end` for every opening keyword (`class`, `def`, etc.)

Comment: I have two ends: one for the `Emailer` class, the other for the `test_email` method.

Comment: @AsarluhiI: if your mailer class is valid, then it's the view (or something else). Ends are definitely unbalanced _somewhere_.

Comment: It is a stand-alone script. I installed the ActionMailer gem in a dedicated rvm gemset, and I run the script as it is: `$ ruby actionmailer.rb`. According to the author of the book ActionMailer can be used independently from Rails.

Comment: @Asarluhi: there are no miracles. Your ends are not balanced. If you post a [mcve], I'm quite sure I'll be able to point out the problem in under a minute.

Comment: Also `@mention` people if you want them to notice your comments.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that my assumption about unbalanced ends is based on an educated guess (and it may turn out to be a problem with something else). Still, I will need an MCVE to help you any further.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for trying to help. If MCVE stands for Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, I think you should consider that the code above is a stand alone script, not embedded in any Rails App and that should be run as it is, removing `self` from the `test_email` method. I upgraded the original message.

Comment: @Asarluhi: indeed, I do get EOF error now. Are SMTP credentials valid?

Comment: Tried with my gmail acc. Same error. Hmm.

Comment: BTW, if you provided the "long" stacktrace as soon as you started receiving the EOF error, we would have avoided this several days of exchange about supposedly unbalanced ends. 21 lines is not long, it's tiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't have a yahoo account to check, but [this configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail) has worked with my gmail account:

```
require 'action_mailer'

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => "sender@gmail.com",
    :password => "<password>",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}


class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def test_email(email_address, email_body)
    mail(to: email_address, from: 'sender@gmail.com', subject: 'action mailer test', body: email_body)
  end
end

Emailer.test_email('recipient@gmail.com', 'This is a test e-mail!').deliver_now
```

Comment: Apparently for yahoo it is necessary to use port 587 and `:enable_starttls_auto => true`: with these changes now it works. I also have a gmail account but I received a `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError` and a notification in my inbox about a blocked sign-in attempt from an app that may put my account at risk. They say I can continue to use this app by allowing access to less secure apps, but this may leave my account vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is using 'self'. Must be

```
def test_email(email_address, email_body)
  ...
end
```

instead of

```
def self.test_email(email_address, email_body)
  ...
end
```

So, `Emailer.test_email.deliver_now` will work. It the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base) we can see that `mail` is instance method but in `self.method_name` available only class methods. A Class Method is a piece of functionality that belongs to that class but is not tied to any particular single instance. The inverse statement is also fair too.
Why is `Emailer` instance instead of a class? It is magic from ActionMailer::Base

Comment: "but test_email is initializer of that class" - but it's not. "initializer" has specific meaning in ruby. There's definitely some magic there, though.

Comment: Also, `Emailer.test_email` returns an `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery`, not an `Emailer`.

Comment: Yes, you right, that is not the initializer and return specific object(from method mail) Mail::Message.

Comment: @Leo you are right, this is how the original code was written, but it still does not work, because I receive a `end of file reached (EOFError)` with a long traceback (21 lines). There is something wrong I can't see

Answer (score 0):

One way that can cause this error message is if you simply have the wrong namespace e.g. I had

```
AlertsMailer.new_user_signup(user).deliver_now
```

but for me it should have been

```
MessagesMailer.new_user_signup(user).deliver_now
```

So rails couldn't find method for that namespace. It pays to double check your code as I learned :)